# Facebook: How to receive app id for official page?

Tags: facebook

Can't find anything in settings. The thing is, that i need to auth users on my website and it requires app id.

I have converted profile into facebook official page.

Thanks.

Comment: As i understand i need to register facebook app separately. And then i can control auth users and control facebook official page via this registered app through access token.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must register your website to get an application ID:

http://developers.facebook.com/setup/

For more details see:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/#login

Comment: So facebook apps and facebook pages are separate departments? Are they related anyhow?

Comment: Facebook pages can host applications within tabs. Applications also have their own Facebook pages.

Comment: But when i'm trying to register facebook application it automatically redirects me to my facebook page. So one user profile can't have both at once(app+pages)?

Comment: "Facebook pages can host applications within tabs" what do you mean by this? Could you more specific please? :)

Comment: @Beck let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2274/discussion-between-jbit-and-beck)

Comment: HI jBit, i'm getting the same problem.  I'm trying to get an App id but I keep getting redirected to my profile page.  How did you get around that?  I've looked at the chat, but I can't see what you did?